# android - change volume device paired with bluetooth

Tags: android, android-bluetooth

We have 2 android mobile.
On `mobile 1` , we installed our app and on `mobile 2`, app not installed.
First, two devices paired with bluetooth (on setting).
Then `mobile 1` open our app.

Now, how can increase and decrease volume on `mobile 2` with app on `mobile 1` programmatically??(Notice: Two devices are paired )

Comment: No body there to help me?!!!

Comment: Too broad. You are basically asking for someone to write your entire solution. Start by implementing one thing at a time. May I suggest you start by studying the Android developer Bluetooth guide: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html

Comment: I hope you are working on a remote audio controlling application.?

Comment: @RubinNellikunnathu yes. I need to change volume mobile 1 with bluetooth pair on mobile 2.